# zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot write zip file to terminal)

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip

I am learning the book A Bite of Python. After typing in the example in the book

```
import os
import time

# 1. The files and directories to be backed up are
# specified in a list.
# Example on Windows:
# source = ['"C:\\MY Documents"', 'C:\\Code']
# Example on Mac OS X and Linux:
source = ['/home/username/Downloads/books']
# Notice we had to use double quotes inside the string
# for  names with spaces in it.

# 2. The backup must be stored in a 
# main backup directory
# Example on Windows:
# target_dir = 'E:\\Backup'
# Example on Mac OS X and Linux:
target_dir = '/home/username/Downloads/backup'
# Remember to change this to which folder you will be using

# 3. The files are backed up into a zip file.
# 4. The name of the zip archive is the current date and time
target = target_dir + os.sep + \
        time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# Create target directory if it is not present
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
    os.mkdir(target_dir)    # make directory

# 5. We use the zip commond to put the files in a zip archive
zip_command = "zip - r {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))

# Run the backup
print "Zip command is:"
print zip_command
print "Running:"
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print 'Successful backup to', target
else:
    print 'Backup FALIED'
```

I goe a message `zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot write zip file to terminal)`
I can not figure out where goes wrong, I type in the same code in this book.
Anyone knows why this happen?

Comment: Print out the value of `zip_command` before you run it.  Is it correct?

Comment: it is the problem of the zip_command, I put extra space in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is in the `zip` command you are creating , there is an extra space between `-` and `r` . Example -

```
zip_command = "zip - r {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
                    ^
Notice the extra space
```

There should be no space between `-` and `r`. Example -

```
zip_command = "zip -r {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source))
```

---

Also, I would like to suggest that, it would be better to use `subprocess.call()` rather than `os.system` , providing it a list of arguments for the command. Example -

```
import subprocess
zip_command = ['zip','-r',target]
for s in source:
    zip_command.append(s)
subprocess.call(zip_command)
```

It would have been easier to see the error this way.